# Where are latex macros such as `\@nx` defined?

Tags: amsmath

I was looking into the `amsmath` documentation, particularly the implementation of `\genfrac`. I find it is difficult to understand because I don't know what commands such as `\@nx` do.

Where is this stuff defined? Is there a list of commands commonly used in core packages, that one should be aware of to understand their implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`amsgen.dtx` source file has

```
% \begin{macro}{\@xp}
% \begin{macro}{\@nx}
%    Shorthands for long command names.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\let\@xp=\expandafter
\let\@nx=\noexpand
%    \end{macrocode}
%    \end{macro}
%    \end{macro}
%
```

Comment: Is there a .dtx file for all standard packages? Also, is the `\begin{macro}` stuff there intended for documentation purposes?

Comment: the doc system is distributed as part of the base latex release so all the standard ones and around half contributed ones use it, see `texdoc amsgen` to see the typeset output. @dow